# Why I cannot split the column into two columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a dataframe['anno'] like this:

```
df.anno

0         type I secretion outer membrane protein, TolC...
1         conserved hypothetical protein [Shigella boyd...
2              Transposase [Congregibacter litoralis KT71]
3         Chain A, The Crystal Structure Of Chlorite Di...
4         chlorite dismutase, partial [uncultured bacte...
5         carbamoyl-phosphate synthase, small subunit [...
6         anthranilate synthase component 1 [endosymbio...
7         chlorite dismutase, partial [bacterium enrich...
8         peptidase dimerization domain protein [Myroid...
9         MULTISPECIES: MFS transporter [Enterobacteria...
10        CAAX amino terminal protease family protein [...
11        Fe-S oxidoreductase [Desulfovibrio africanus ...
12        phosphoenolpyruvate synthase/pyruvate phospha...
```

Because there are two parts in every row: 1: protein name. 2. microbial species with '[......]'.

I want to extract the protein name part and discard the microbial species, so I decided first to split the column into two columns at the position '['.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.anno.str.split("[", 1).tolist(), columns = ['protein','species'])
```

It returns an error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

I also tried:

```
df[['protein','species']] =  df['anno'].str.split('[', expand=True)
```

It also returned an error:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

How to do this? Are there any other ways to extract the protein names?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is problem multiple `[`, so was added `n=1` to [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for split by first `[`. For remove last `]` use [`rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html):

```
df[['protein','species']] =  df['anno'].str.rstrip(']').str.split('[', expand=True, n=1)
```

For strip by last `[` use [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html):

```
df[['protein','species']] =  df['anno'].str.rstrip(']').str.rsplit('[', expand=True, n=1)
```

Another solution with [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for extract by last `[]`:

```
df[['protein','species']] = df['anno'].str.extract('(.*)\[(.*)\]', expand=True)
```

Sample:

```
df[['protein','species']] =  df['anno'].str.rstrip(']').str.split('[', expand=True, n=1) 
df['species'] = df['species'].str.replace('\]\[',',')
df['protein'] = df['protein'].str.strip()
print (df)
                 anno      protein species
0     protein [q][sd]      protein    q,sd
1             protein      protein    None
2  Transposase [KT71]  Transposase    KT71
3                None         None    None
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! One problem: for row[3], the value it's like this: ' Chain A, The Crystal Structure Of Chlorite Dismutase: A Detox Enzyme Producing Molecular Oxygen'
It doesn't have a species name. If I run the command, it will give me NaN for bothe 'protein' and 'species'. What should I do if I want to keep the protein name?

Comment: The problem is some values in the column doesn't have '[species name..]' in it. If I use str.extract, it will return NaN. If I use str.split, it will return error.

Comment: I tried adding n=1, still got this error:  TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: Hmmm, then I have no idea if use my solution - `df[['protein','species']] =  df['anno'].str.rstrip(']').str.split('[', expand=True, n=1)` - for me it working nice with `None` and `NaN`s too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. I tried and it worked in my case. Can you explain  "extract('(.*)\[(.*)\]', expand=True)" what is going on in 'extract'? So many (), *, \, [],....Thanks.

Comment: It is really easy - need extract 2 groups of values. First all values to last [ and then values to last ].